# Correlation Chart Series Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, spatial-statistics

I'm going to get correlation series between LAI and FAPAR using NOAA AVHRR data by the below code in Google Earth Engine but returns error. Does anyone has idea?

Error message: Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f72e97bd596381e406d42839adf66f3c

```
 var noaaLAI = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/CDR/AVHRR/LAI_FAPAR/V5")
.filterDate('1980','1984')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.select('LAI','FAPAR')
.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.001)
  .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
  });

  
print(
  ui.Chart.image.series(noaaLAI, geometry, ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(),
  10000, 'system:time_start')
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a multi-input reducer in the chart helper functions.  Instead, map the reducer over your inputs and produce a time-series with a single value per date, and then chart that.

Comment: I'm not agree, because this code works for other satellite examples: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/2108b29720f83c7af47adde18a671acd

Comment: My mistake, you're correct, but doing the map yourself shows that you're getting 2 NaNs in the results.  You'll have to filter those images out.  https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8f7d11c491c0d004c5b812a8ee760da